# Adding a directory to $PATH doesn't work in Yosemite

Tags: macos, bash, path

I've tried to do it both ways:

1. I edited `~/.bash_profile` like so:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="${PATH};~/bin"
$ $ ls -l ~/.bash_profile 
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  staff  202 Oct  1 16:57 /Users/myuser/.bash_profile
```

2. I edited `/etc/paths` like so:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/myuser/bin
```

So now my path looks like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myuser/bin;~/bin
```

But I still can't run the files I have in `~/bin`:

```
$ ls -l ~/bin
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser  staff  38 Oct  1 13:44 dev
$ dev
bash: dev: command not found
```

I haven't restarted my Mac yet, but I opened a new terminal to do the above test. How can I get the files in `~/bin` to work without having to type their full path?

Comment: I just did this, and It worked fine for me. I used `~/bin` in my `/etc/paths` instead of my username.

Comment: You have a typo there is a semi colon (not colon) in your path just before ~/bin  - which is from your ~/.bash_profile - you have not tried the  /etc/paths on its own

Comment: @IronCraftMan: Yup. You can put that as the answer.